# How can I create a vCard qrcode with pyqrcode?

Tags: python, django, vcf-vcard

I am trying to generate a vCard QR code with the pyqrcode library but I cannot figure out the way to do it.

I have read their documentation 5 times and it doesn't say anything about vCard, only about URL and on the internet, I could found only about wifi. Does anybody know how can I do it?

I want to make a vCard QR code and afterward to display it on django web page.

Comment: You could generate  QR from any string, you only need to send a string. I worked with vobject==0.9.3  https://pypi.org/project/vobject/  to manage vcards

Comment: Then you need to read a vCard, serialize as string and Create a QR with pyqrcode.create(vcard_string)  . Check https://github.com/mnooner256/pyqrcode , usage ex: `qr = pyqrcode.create('Unladden swallow')`

Comment: @Mate How would the vcard_string look like? for example in segno it is like this qr = helpers.make_vcard(name='Doe;John', displayname='John Doe', email='me@example.org', phone='+1234567') ?

Comment: Here http://eventable.github.io/vobject/ , in vCard section you could find some examples.  Usually likes as `'BEGIN:VCARD\r\nVERSION:3.0\r\nEMAIL;TYPE=INTERNET:jeffrey@osafoundation.org\r\nFN:Jeffrey Harris\r\nN:Harris;Jeffrey;;;\r\nEND:VCARD\r\n'`

Comment: @Mate but the one you shared with me it is for vobject library not for pyqrcode library, is it the same? if not how would look the example for pyqrcode ?

Comment: I shared a vCard string further any library. If you open a .vcard file with some text editor you'll find the same.   Now, you could use any library to parse, serialize/deserialize. The final format will be like the example.  your input/ouput is a .vcard file or do you just want share some info ?

Comment: @Mate I needed both but I already understood how it works with vcard file now if I want to share info in this format? like when I scan with the app to receive all the information and the vcard type as well not like a usual string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say :

We've two libraries:

1. pyqrcode : QR      reader / writer
2. vobject   : vCard  serializer /    deserializer

Flow:

a. Generate a QR img from "some" web site :

web site send JSON info => get info from JSON and serialize using vobject to obtain a vcard string =>   pyqrcode.create(vcard string)

b. Show human redeable info from QR img  :

pyqrcode read an QR img ( created from a. )  => deserialize using vobject to obtain a JSON => show info parsing JSON in the web site.

OR... after deserialize using vobject you can write a .vcard file

Answer (score 4):

1. Use [python-qrcode](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode) as the QR generator.
2. Type the string for the QR using the vCard 3 format, sample below:

```py
data = '''BEGIN:VCARD

VERSION:3.0

N:Lastname;Surname

FN:Displayname

ORG:EVenX

URL:URL HERE

EMAIL:SOME@EMAIL.COM

TEL;TYPE=voice,work,pref:+49 1234 56788

ADR;TYPE=intl,work,postal,parcel:;;Wallstr. 1;Tehran;;12345;Iran

END:VCARD'''
```

3. Save the QR into a file and you just generated a vCard from Python.

Comment: vCard format specification: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6350.html